# How can i change bluetooth name whiile doing BLE advertisement in windows?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying with Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement Library to send Advertisement. but currently, from the receiver side, I am getting N/A as the Bluetooth name.

Are there any options to set Bluetooth names in windows? If not then IF we can set the name from machine-name? (currently it's showing N/A)

Currently i Implemented below code

`namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher publisher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher();
        ///////Note - Localname can't be use as it's  system-reserved and are not allowed
        ///https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementpublisher?view=winrt-22621#remarks
        // publisher.Advertisement.LocalName = "hello";
        // Add custom data to the advertisement
        //var manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData();
        // var datasection = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection();

        //manufacturerData.CompanyId = 0x7008;
        //   datasection.DataType = 0xEF;

        var writer = new DataWriter();
        var writer1 = new DataWriter();
       var writer2 = new DataWriter();
         writer.WriteString("Hello World");
        writer1.WriteString("avhsafj");
        writer2.WriteString("hgsf");
        //UInt16 uuidData = 0x2252;
        //writer.WriteUInt16(uuidData);

        // Make sure that the buffer length can fit within an advertisement payload (~20 bytes). 
        // Otherwise you will get an exception.
        //manufacturerData.Data = writer.DetachBuffer();
       // datasection.Data = writer1.DetachBuffer();


        var manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData(
          0x7008, writer.DetachBuffer());

        var datasection = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection(
          0xEF, writer1.DetachBuffer());

        var datasection1 = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection(
       0xFF, writer2.DetachBuffer());

        // Add the manufacturer data to the advertisement publisher:
        publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);
        publisher.Advertisement.DataSections.Add(datasection);
        publisher.Advertisement.DataSections.Add(datasection1);
       
        publisher.Start();
    }

}
```

}
`

Comment: You don't advertise any Name, so don't expect to see any name. Take your mobile and use an app like [nRFConnet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp) to understand what you source code is doing.

Comment: The Short and Long name advertisement packets ID are reserved by the system and can not be used in custom advertismeents. The only way to change the visible (advertised) name is to change the dongle's name itself (it is the same for classic and LE).

Comment: Thanks, @Risto . Yes, I used it. But in that android app, I am getting "N/A" as the name. I checked android is providing a facility to change the name.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Android and Linux applications can change Bluetooth names. So, Why can't do the same thing on Windows?

Comment: It's better to ask from Microsoft. You question looks like: Boeing 737 and Starship can fly, why my car can't?

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thank you for your time. As of now, we can't set name then can we assure that we can get name of Bluetooth from machine_name as currently we are getting N/A as name.

Comment: As I wrote above (if you read it correctly) advertisement includes the device name that is set for Bluetooth dongle. I do not know what you use on receiver side but Windows always advertises the system advertisement packets and one of them includes device name.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I am using the nRFConnet android app to verify my advertisement.

Comment: nRFConnect is not tool to capture few advertisement packets. Use something that can trace/log all received packets and you'll find the name.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I am using a windows 10 laptop, And I am publishing a BLE advertisement I created one console app who are listing each and every packet of BLE. But each time it's showing the manufacturer id correct with no Bluetooth name. Why windows is not setting any name (machine name) in an advertisement? Any Idea?

Comment: Once again: Windows ALWAYS advertises name, custom MS specific packate and your advertisements. Use BluetoothLeAdvertisementWatcher to capture all advertisements in RAW format and you will find the device's name there.

Comment: Yes @MikePetrichenko I use that class and receive method to check. I am checking args.Advertisement.GetManufacturerDataByCompanyId to get my packet and args.Advertisement.LocalName to check name but name is always null.

Comment: Again: parse raw data manually.